# Is end-systolic volume (ESV) the same as residual volume?

Tags: physiology, cardiology

I am reading [this site](http://apbrwww5.apsu.edu/thompsonj/Anatomy%20&%20Physiology/2020/2020%20Exam%20Reviews/Exam%201/CH18%20Cardiac%20Cycle.htm) and my study materials.
The end-systolic volume (ESV), 50-60 ml, is the volume of blood found in ventricles after systole and contraction of ventricles.

I think ESV is the same as residual volume because residual volume is always the volume found in ventricles.

**Is ESV the same as residual volume in normal physiological situations?**

Comment: I am not completely sure that ESV can correspond residual volume in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESV is the residual volume of blood remaining in the ventricle after ejection. 
It is the minimum volume of blood in the ventricles (residual volume). 
Note that you can also have residual volume of air in the lungs after exhalation.